# SanKey diagram in R - networkD3 library CUSTOMIZE ID NODE POSITION

Tags: javascript, r, networkd3

I'd like to get a plot in which the ID of the nodes on the left will display externally from the network (as for the node on the right).

Could someone suggest the right option to do that?
Thanks in advance!

This is my code to generate my sankey plot

`sankeyNetwork(Links = data_long, Nodes = nodes, Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",  sinksRight=FALSE, colourScale=my_color, LinkGroup = "group", nodeWidth=50, fontSize=13, nodePadding=22)`

This is the output...

[image]

Which option can I add tomy script in order to get the label of the left nodes on the external side?